# Large rep value on new Top Bar obscures adjacent inbox value

Tags: bug, design, top-bar

I just saw the top-nav bar for the first time.  The reputation number was incorrect, showing +1013 when it should have been on the order of +20.  This was especially noticeable because the width of "+1013" causes the rep count delta to occlude the inbox count.

[image]

Comment: Also, do any of those items "centre", and, if so, on what?

Comment: This isn't a bug about an incorrect value, it's about a large value. My “achievements” number shows 45511, and for all I know it's correct (I never use that box, it only resets when I accidentally click it or press the keyboard shortcut).

Comment: Are you sure?  It seems to me, in the old top-bar nav, I'd typically see a number that represented my rep change since my last login.  Am I remembering wrong?  (It was only yesterday.)

Comment: @BillWoodger: They seem to be right-justified on the side of the icon.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas:  The two sentences in your comment seem to contradict each other.  I'm guessing you meant to say "incorrectly."

Comment: The rep notification is only reset when you click on it.

Comment: @Tiny Giant:  That was always true on the profile page, but not in the top bar.

Comment: No, that's the way it has been in the top bar since I started using the site two years ago

Comment: @Tiny Giant:  Do you sign in each day or leave a tab open that's always signed in?  I sign in each day, and I swear it's only ever shown rep counts since my last sign in.  I don't recall _ever_ clicking it.

Comment: I sign in and sign out at least once a day

Comment: @TinyGiant checking in from an internet cafe?

Comment: @canon I check in at work, on my mobile phone, at home, basically everywhere I am I'm connected to Stack Overflow somehow.

Comment: @TinyGiant same here and it always resets when I click the link on the bar to open the rep popup.

Comment: this seems like an edge case.

Comment: Perhaps the rep box should start showing "+1k" instead of "+1013".

Comment: My first impression: You asked this question to show off how large your rep gain is :-)

Comment: @usr1234567 _"The reputation number was incorrect, showing +1013 when it should have been on the order of +20"_